# How to stop inner div to overlap outer div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when i click the large button, the `smaller` div increases width to 300px. And the red line shows above the black dotted borders.

Is there a way that when I click, the black dotted border remains front, and red border on back?  Here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/K4L5s/

Thanks

Comment: Periods are your friend.

Comment: @AdamTerlson sorry i didnt understand..

Comment: you shouldn't use fixed width for outer div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add position:relative & change z-index: http://jsfiddle.net/K4L5s/13/

Comment: Ah i've completely mis-read the problem, I thought he wanted the outer box to expand as well. My bad.

Comment: @Prisoner reread the question, all hira is asking is to get the red lines behind the black ones...

Comment: I know, that's what I just said?

Answer (score 4):

Add a `overflow:hidden;` to the larger div's css.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish? If you just want the div to fill the parent, set the width to 100%:

```
$("#Large").click(function(){
    $("#smaller").width("100%");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by giving your child element a **negative** `z-index`, and `position: absolute`. Of course, then you open up a whole new can of worms with positioning...

Answer (score 2):

```
#smaller
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but it sounds like you're looking for z-index. Unfortunately, you can't use z-index without also applying a position that allows it. This is what it sounds like you're looking for:

```
#bigger
{
    border-style:dotted;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
#smaller
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Just make sure you don't have a z-index on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

depending on what browser(s) you're trying to support, you could set the max-width proprty of the smaller div.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed width on the outer div, so it won't increase.

The small div is overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Give the higher z Index to the bigger Div. it will resolve your problem